# How to dump my class(with stl container) out, make it fast to load next time?

Tags: c++, serialization, stl

I have a large container class to read file and save some data, it looks like:

```
class MyData {
 public:
  void Load(const std::vector<string>& file_paths) {  // this is a slow funuction, need to read a lot of files.
     for (const auto & f : file_paths) {
       // read file, and save the data in to stl containers
     }
  }
 private:
  std::vector<double> a;
  std::unordered_map<string, double>b; // there may be more containers.
}
```

everytime when i need to use this class, i need to:

```
MyData mdata;
std::vector<std::string> fs; // thousands of files need to read
mdata.Load(fs); // very slow
```

but the Mdata not update frequently, Can i dump it out, and use the dumped class, so make it faster?
For example:

```
MyData load_dump(const std::string& dump_file_path) {
  // help needed
}

const MyData& mdata = load_dump("dump.bin"); // load the dumped file, to speed up
```

Can you help on this?

Comment: We don't know what is in Load(), apart that it is slow....  Why is it slow?  What does the code look like?  Even file with a relatively complex format (multi-streams, mixed binary + xml) usually load in a couple of ms.  Show some code, there is not much we can do to help without code.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy ok, thanks for reminding, the reason of slow is i need to load thousands of files, it need more than 10 s.

Comment: Why do you feel the need to save `mdata`, can't just stay in memory? Have you resources constraints? How often you have to refresh it, reloading its source files?

Comment: @MatG  because i use it a lot, everytime i start the program, it will cost me 10s to load. I dont know how to make it saved in memory permantly, i think that's what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can.  For `vector<double>` you can simply use `ofstream::write(a.data(), a.size())`.  For things like maps you need to do some kind of serialization because their internal representation is more complex.  You could use http://www.boost.org/libs/serialization/ for a somewhat generic solution or you could write the code yourself.